# Scraping articles on a web site

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, express.js

I'm trying to create a scraping API in Express. The API scrapes the different articles featured on the home page.

Here are the issues I'm trying to resolve:

- My code's turning into a ton of jquery select statements. How can I resolve this / How can I simplify my code or extract functions from this giant mass?
- Are my variable names clear enough?
- Are there any Node conventions I'm not following? I've seen a lot of `let` and I'm using `var`. If I'm doing anything wrong let me know.

Here is the block of code I'm running:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs      = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app     = express();

app.get('/scrape', function(req, res){
  url = 'http://anawesomewebsite.com';

  request(url, function(error, response, html){
    if(!error){
      var $ = cheerio.load(html);

      var title, url, image;
      var articles = [];
      var article = { title : "", url : "", image_src : ""};

      //Get articles featured at top of page
      var i = 0;
      $(".articles li .img img").each(function(){
          var image_src = $(this).attr('src');
          article.image_src = image_src;
          articles[i] = article;
          i = i + 1;
      });

      i = 0;
      $(".articles li a[class='title']").each(function(){
         var title = $(this).text();
         var url = $(this).attr('href');
         article.title = title;
         article.url = "http://vegnews.com" + url;
         articles[i] = article;
         i = i + 1;
      });

      //Get articles featured at bottom of page
      var number_of_articles_beforehand = articles.length;
      i = number_of_articles_beforehand;

      $(".article .image img").each(function(){
        var image_src = $(this).attr('src');
        article.image_src = image_src;
        articles[i] = article;
        i = i + 1;
      });

      i = number_of_articles_beforehand;
      $(".article .image a").each(function(){
         var url = $(this).attr('href');
         article.url = url
         articles[i] = article;
         i = i + 1;
      })

      i = number_of_articles_beforehand;
      $(".article .title").each(function(){
        var title = $(this).text();
        article.title = title;
        articles[i] = article;
        i = i + 1;
      })

    }
    res.send(articles);
  })
})

app.listen('8081')
console.log('Magic happens on port 8081');
exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: fwiw, you can simplify your loops as `$(".articles li .img img").each( function(i) {` and not worry about incrementing the loop counter yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is to always start breaking code into smaller methods however in your case I suggest you change your logic. Instead of looping through each element updating a list of articles rather loop through each `li` creating a complete article something like:

```
request(url, function(error, response, html){
  if(!error){
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    const articles = $('.article li').map( (i, el) => getArticle($(el) );
    res.send(articles);
  }
});

function getArticle($el) {
  return {
     image_src: $el.find('.img img").attr('src'),
     title:     $el.find("a[class='title']").text(),
     url:       "http://vegnews.com" + $el.find("a[class='title']").attr(href),
 }
}
```

(This will perform slightly worse but will be much easier to maintain IMO)

BTW there is a bug here:

```
  var article = { title : "", url : "", image_src : ""};
  ...
  $(".articles li .img img").each(function(){
      ...
      articles[i] = article;
  });
```

You are assigning (sharing) the same article over and over not creating a new one. Each time through the loop you just overwrite the attributes.

Answer (score 5):

1. As for the jQuery/function usage, there is definitely room for improvement but it would be helpful to see an example HTML element that contains the article `img`, `title`, and `url` to understand the page structure a bit.
2. I think your variable names are clear, but could be simplified. Also, it is common practice to use Camel Case with the first letter lowercase for Node/Javascript instead of underscores between words.

   - For example, replace `number_of_articles_beforehand` with `numArticlesBefore`
3. Here is an article I found helpful regarding `var`, `let`, `const`

   - https://medium.com/javascript-scene/javascript-es6-var-let-or-const-ba58b8dcde75
   - Javascript allows variable hoisting (click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) for more info) with the keyword `var` whereas variables/identifiers declared as `let` or `const` do not hoist.
   - Personally, I have stopped using `var` altogether to help improve code readability as mentioned in the article above. Also, it is common practice to use `const` for the Node package require statements instead of var.
   - Remove the `var title, url, image;` line because you are only using those variables within their respective functions.
   - Lastly, I would encourage you to replace `i = i + 1;` with `i++;`. It does the same thing and is easier to read. (FYI, `i--;` would decrement `i` by 1).